# Using Reduce() with a list of functions from an imported package

Tags: r, namespaces

I am currently trying to create a package and have been following the advice of Hadley Wickham by doing calls to the namespace instead of @import packagename in Roxygen.

I have this function:

```
make_plot <- function(data, x, y, groups = NULL, error.params = list(),
                      graph.params = list(), ...) {

  ggplot(data, aes(x, y, colour = groups)) +
    build_bar_graph(error.params, graph.params) +
    build_graph_options(...)

}
```

that calls

```
build_graph_options <- function(...) {
  Reduce("+", list(...), accumulate = TRUE)
}
```

where ... is expected to be, for example, xlab(), ylab() and other ggplot2 functions.

However I run into two issues:

1. If I do not @import in roxygen, I must prefix every element of list(...) with ggplot2::. I've tried doing so with lapply and paste0, but it only works for strings and when I try it tries to call xlab() and ylab() inside lapply.
2. If I @import all of ggplot2, I can use ggplot() without ggplot2:: (see first function), but Reduce() comes back with  `Error in ylab("Mean growth") : could not find function "ylab"`. If I add ggplot2:: to my arguments, however, it works fine.

I am calling make_plot like so:

```
make_plot(test.summary, dose, statistic, groups = supp,
          error.params = list(width = .5),
          graph.params = list(colour = "black"),
          xlab("Dose (mg)"), ylab("Mean growth"))
```

which doesn't work unless I replace xlab() with ggplot2::xlab(), etc.

Is there a way to avoid forcing the use of ggplot2:: or prefixing my functions with ggplot2:: without user input?

Comment: Not importing a package works fine for functions used internally. Sounds like you want the user to specify `ggplot2` functions, so we can say they are used *externally*, not just *internally*. `ggplot2` is a common package; if your package uses it heavily (and expects the user to know how to use it, e.g., knowing functions like `xlab` and `ylab`), you can Import it or even Depend on it.